# Display previous input on keyup from user, in Python?

Tags: python, shell, input, onkeyup

I have a simple Python program which uses a read-eval-print loop to read user input via `raw_input` and then print things to the screen. I would like to keep a history of previous inputs and cycle through them when the user presses keyup or keydown, similar to the Python interpreter or to the bash shell. How can I do this in Python?

Someone asked for sample code:

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input()
    print user_input + " this many hats!!!"
```

I'd like to make it so a keyup puts the last line of input on the command line. The first answer given, use the `readline` module, is likely the best.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the [`readline`](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) module.  If your platform supports readline, simply importing the module should make its functionality available via the `raw_input` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For standard `input` function also works. No configuration needed. Just import `readline`.